# OpenMP reduction issue with Cython

Tags: gcc, clang, openmp, cython, reduction

I am facing an unexpected behavior of Cython (v. 0.29.13) when compiling OpenMP parallel code that is expect to perform a reduction:

```
import cython
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel

cpdef omp_test1(n):
    cdef int sum = 0, i, imax
    imax = <int>n
    for i in prange(imax, nogil=True):
        sum += 1
    return sum


cpdef omp_test2(n):
    cdef int sum = 0, i, imax
    imax = <int>n
    with nogil, parallel():
        for i in prange(imax):
            sum += 1
    return sum
```

When calling both functions I would expect to have as a return value the input argument `n`. Instead, the returned value is `n * num_threads`. Surprisingly, on my Mac this unexpected behavior is observed only with GCC (v. 9.2.0_2); the clang (v. 11.0.0) returns the expected value `n`.

Is there something wrong I am doing or is there a problem with the generated Cython code or GCC compiler?

Comment: This probably isn't helpful but it works fine for me (Linux GCC 9.2.1, Cython 0.29.13)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. I've also run it successfully, as DavidW has.

I am testing OpenMP parallelised Cython code in an automatic way on multiple operating systems and with different Python versions. Once in a while, we have problems on MacOS, but with clang.

This won't solve your problem, but as a hint, you should look at the compilers or your OpenMP version.